# How to implement proper switchMap operator in Combine?

Tags: swift, combine

Consider the following example:

```
    cancellable = Just(2).map { x in
        Just(x * x).delay(for: 2.0, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
    }
    .switchToLatest()
    .sink(receiveCompletion: {_ in
        print("completed")
    }, receiveValue: {result in
        print(result)
    })
```

Here I try to mimic behavior of famous switchMap operator using Combine operators. I expect to get result after two seconds and completion. In reality neither result nor completion comes.
Which is very bad because upstream was completed!

Looks like switchToLatest cancels itself as soon as upstream completes and forgets to complete. 
On the other hand if I replace it with a `flatMap` everything works as expected.

Are there any good examples of a proper switchMap operator?

Disclaimer: Well I do understand my upstream completes. Though I want my switchMap to work irrespectively if my upstream completed before inner publisher or after.

Comment: Yuck seems like another bug in Combine. I've been struggling with a combination of `.receive(on: queue).combineLatest(Just(2))`. Just goes silent like in your example, and `flatMap` works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for asking that question; this just bit me too, so I'm happy to find out I'm not alone.

Comment: The bug is fixed in Xcode 11.4

Answer (score 0):

Did not you mean for the following (at least, as far as I understood, it results in what seems you expected)?

```
let cancellable = Just(2)
    .map { x in
        Just(x * x)
    }
    .delay(for: 2.0, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
    .switchToLatest()
    .sink(receiveCompletion: {_ in
        print("completed")
    }, receiveValue: {result in
        print(result)
    })
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant. I wanted to show that the following example doesn't generate outputs and completed events which is an error by itself. Also in your example you delayed the output of a map while I delayed inner observable of the map which caused the behavior in question.

Comment: To make it even simpler: I think that `publisher.map(transform).switchToLatest()` should generate events even if publisher completes before inner publisher.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a bug. Try using `flatMap` instead, which works as expected.

```
let cancellable = Just(2)
.flatMap { (x) in
    Just(x * x)
        .delay(for: 2.0, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
}
.sink(receiveCompletion: {_ in
    print("completed")
}, receiveValue: {result in
    print(result)
})
```

Comment: True, except that `flatMap` is not what I want :-) I want a `switchMap` actually. Imagine I have a stream instead of `Just()` and I do want to cancel previous subscriptions when it emits. Well I already implemented a custom operator doing it so probably will post it here later.

Comment: @norekhov please post your solution, would love to learn from it.

Comment: @norekhov btw there are really not many docs available to be fair, I follow this unofficial one: https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#reference-operators-adaptingtypes. Based on what it says there is no difference between `.map().switchToLatest()` and `.flatMap()`. Are you coming from ReactiveCocoa perhaps?

Comment: You can check my solution here: https://github.com/tcldr/Entwine/issues/16. Maybe it will be included in Entwine or the author will suggest some other workaround. This is actually only `switchToLatestWaitable` but it can be combined with map to form proper switchMap

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `switchToLatest` is probably what you're looking for. The problem is that it is buggy. Or at least it was; the bug is fixed in Xcode 11.4 (currently in beta) and now `switchToLatest` behaves exactly as one would expect. Your code now works correctly:

```
    Just(2).map { x in
        Just(x * x).delay(for: 2.0, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
    }
    .switchToLatest()
    .sink(receiveCompletion: {_ in
        print("completed")
    }, receiveValue: {result in
        print(result)
    }).store(in:&storage)  // 4, completed
```

Comment: When you say this is fixed in Xcode 11.4, does it mean that any devices running iOS 13.3 or below will be affected by this bug? I'm guessing the version of Combine that shipedp with those OSs is buggy so whether the binary was built with Xcode 11.4 or not does not make a difference, would you agree?

Comment: @Rog That is what I think it means, yes. Basically this feature of Combine did not become usable until iOS 13.4. It's a pity, but that is what I think happened. Fortunately it is extremely improbable that any user with iOS 13 would not have updated to iOS 13.4 or later. — But you can test this for yourself, there's no need to speculate.